# wchar_t encoding on different platforms

Tags: c, encoding

I faced a problem with encodings on different platforms (in my case Windows and Linux). On windows, size of wchar_t is 2 bytes, whereas on Linux it's 4 bytes. How can I "standardize" wchar_t to be same size for both platforms? Is it hard to implement without additional libraries? For now, I'm aiming for printf/wprintf API. The data is sent via socket communication. Thank you.

Comment: The useful things you can do with `wchar_t` are not portable, and the portable things you can do with `wchar_t` are not useful.  Sorry, use something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send Unicode data across different platforms and architectures, I'd suggest using **UTF-8** encoding and (8-bit) `char`s. UTF-8 has some advantages like not having endiannes issues (UTF-8 is just a plain sequence of bytes, instead both UTF-16 and UTF-32 can be little-endian or big-endian...).

On Windows, just convert the UTF-8 text to UTF-16 at the boundary of Win32 APIs (since Windows APIs tend to work with UTF-16). You can use the `MultiByteToWideChar()` API for that.

Comment: See http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ for a more thorough discussion of why this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking why I could not think something about this hehe. Solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I think you are going to have to convert all strings into UTF-8 before transmitting.  On Windows you would use the [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert wchar_t strings to UTF-8 strings, and [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert UTF-8 strings into wchar_t strings.

On Linux things aren't as straightforward.  You can use the functions [wctomb](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3/wctomb/) and [mbtowc](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3/mbtowc/), however what they convert to/from depends on the underlying locale setting.  So if you want these to convert to/from UTF-8 and Unicode then you'll need to make sure the locale is set to use UTF-8 encoding.

[This](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) article might also be a good resource.

Comment: On Linux you can use `iconv_open("UTF-8", "WCHAR_T")` to open an `iconv()` conversion descriptor to convert from `wchar_t` strings to UTF-8 strings (and swapped for the reverse).